# How to model this?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, binary-variable, logical-constraints

$i$ is a set $1$ to $n$.

$j$ is a set $1$ to $m$.

$j$ and $k$ are from the same set such that $j\neq k$.

$c_{ij}$ is a parameter.

$x_{ij}$ and $y_{j}$ are binary variables.

How to model: If
$$c_{ij}\cdot y_{j} \ge c_{ik}\cdot y_{k}, \forall i,j,k,j\neq k$$ then $$x_{ij} \ge x_{ik}, \forall i,j,k,j\neq k$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your quantifiers are misplaced and you instead want to enforce
$$\bigwedge_{i,j,k,j\neq k} \left(c_{ij} y_j \ge c_{ik} y_k \implies x_{ij} \ge x_{ik}\right)$$
Equivalently,
$$\bigwedge_{i,j,k,j\neq k} \left(x_{ij} < x_{ik} \implies c_{ij} y_j < c_{ik} y_k \right)$$
$$\bigwedge_{i,j,k,j\neq k} \left(\lnot x_{ij} \land x_{ik} \implies c_{ij} y_j < c_{ik} y_k \right)$$
Introduce constants $\epsilon > 0$ and $M_{ijk} = \max(c_{ij},0) -\min(c_{ik},0) + \epsilon$ and binary variable $z_{ijk}$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
(1 - x_{ij}) + x_{ik} - 1 &\le z_{ijk} \tag1\label1 \\
c_{ij} y_j - c_{ik} y_k + \epsilon &\le M_{ijk}(1 - z_{ijk}) \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces
$\lnot x_{ij} \land x_{ik} \implies z_{ijk}$.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces
$z_{ijk} \implies c_{ij} y_j + \epsilon \le c_{ik} y_k$.

If $c$ is integer-valued, you can take $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! What is this way of constructing constraints is called? It is really beautiful. Is there any papers or books that I can read to learn more about this subject? I'll check the other solution by @prubin too, thank you so much too!

Comment: Constraint \eqref{2} is a big-M constraint, and there is a [big-m] tag for it.  See also https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbooks%5D+williams

Comment: What is the logic behind that ϵ cannot take the value of 0? Is it correct for it to take very small values (such as $ϵ={10}^{-8}$ )? Or how do I decide what value I should give? Well, I know it depends on the $c_{ij}$ parameters, but in general do you think it is always safe to take it as very small values?

Comment: The (small) tolerance $\epsilon>0$ is a measure of how different  $c_{ij}y_j$ must be from $c_{ik}y_k$ for you to consider them to be different.

Answer (score 1):

Since $y$ is binary, $c_{ij}\cdot y_j - c_{ik}\cdot y_k \in S_{ijk} = \lbrace0,-c_{ik},c_{ij},c_{ij}-c_{ik}\rbrace.$ For each combination of subscripts let $P_{ijk}$ and $N_{ijk}$ be respectively the largest nonnegative value and the largest strictly negative value in $S_{ijk}.$ (For now we will assume that at least one set element is negative.) Now consider the constraint $$c_{ij}\cdot y_j - c_{ik}\cdot y_k \le P_{ijk} + (P_{ijk}-N_{ijk})(x_{ij}-x_{ik}).$$ Note that $N_{ijk}<0\implies P_{ijk}-N_{ijk} > 0.$ If $x_{ij} - x_{ik} \ge 0,$ the constraint puts no limits on $y_j$ and $y_k.$ If $x_{ij}-x_{ik}=-1,$ however, you have $c_{ij}\cdot y_j - c_{ik}\cdot y_k \le N_{ijk} < 0.$ So we have enforced the contrapositive of your constraint.

If all elements of $S_{ijk}$ are nonnegative, your antecedent is automatically true, so you can just add $x_{ij}\ge x_{ik}$ as a constraint.